# Alternatives to NDJSON?

Tags: go, serialization

I need a disk serialization format which:

- Supports utf8 or binary data
- Supports multiple messages per file (like newline delimited json)
- (possibly) Is schemaless
- (possibly) Has both a node and a rust implementation

I couldn't find a way for `msgpack` or `CBOR` to support multiple messages per file in go, although it's supported by cbor (sequences). At the moment I'm playing with `asn.1` and it seems nice but I was wondering if there was a better alternative.

Comment: [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value) plus `encoding/binary`.

Comment: Isn't it a bit over engineering? I bet there are existing implementation.... But yes I already started working on it 

Comment: Well, please take no offence but your question as stated sounds weird enough so I assumed you're just feeling adventurous and hence offerred a supposedly minimal toolset to do what you want. If you really want a ready-made framework then pick literally any serialization library: if it supports arrays or list or any _sequence of elements_ for that matter, it does support "multiple messages per file" automatically. `msgpack` does, and so does every other "binary encoder" I've come across.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I couldnt make it work either with cbor or msgpack, an example in either format would be accepted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work both with asn.1 and cbor, I need to try msgpack now

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    type Record struct {
        Payload string
        Counter int
    }

    r1 := Record{
        "hello", 1}
    r2 := Record{
        " world", 2}

    var buff []byte

    b, err := cbor.Marshal(r1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    buff = append(buff, b...)

    b, err = cbor.Marshal(r2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    buff = append(buff, b...)

    log.Println(buff)

    var out1, out2 Record
    decoder := cbor.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(buff))

    err = decoder.Decode(&out1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(out1)

    err = decoder.Decode(&out2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(out2)

}
```